# How do I change the color of a variable in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like **only** the number in `computerScore` and `playerScore` to change color. Is it possible to do this in CSS?

```js
function computerPlay(){
  let values = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'],
  valueToUse = values [Math.floor(Math.random()* values.length)];
  return valueToUse;
};

const rock = document.querySelector('#rock');
const paper = document.querySelector('#paper');
const scissors = document.querySelector('#scissors');
let computerSelection = document.querySelector('.computerSelection');
let result = document.querySelector('.result');
let score = document.querySelector('.computerScore', computerScore = 0, 'playerScore', playerScore = 0);


rock.addEventListener('click', pickRock) 

function pickRock() { 
  let comp = computerPlay()//the variable comp had to be created. Otherwirse, if I use computerPlay() in if statements, sometimes the text content would not appear. See stackoverflow comment.
  if (comp === 'Rock') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Rock";
    result.textContent = "It's a Tie!"
    score.textContent = `Computer Score: ${computerScore +=0} Your Score: ${playerScore +=0}`
    
  } else if (comp === 'Paper') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Paper";
    result.textContent = "Sorry! Paper beats Rock";
    score.textContent = `Computer Score: ${computerScore +=1} Your Score: ${playerScore +=0}`
    
  } else if (comp === 'Scissors') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Scissors";
    result.textContent = "Great Job! Rock beats Scissors";
    score.textContent = `Computer Score: ${computerScore +=0} Your Score: ${playerScore +=1}`
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My javascript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h1>
      <h3>Instructions:</h3>
      <p>You will be playing against the computer. There will be a total of 3 rounds. Good luck!</p>
      <h2 id="choose">Choose:</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <button>
        <img id="rock" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/477914-200.png">
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p class='computerSelection'></p>
      <p class='result'></p>
      <p class='computerScore'></p>
      <p class='playerScore'></p>
      <p class='finalResult'></p>
    </main>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean changing the text color?

Comment: Output the `computerScore` and `playerScore` variables into elements and style those elements with CSS; as you're using `textContent` to show the scores you can't select the relevant text independently of any of the other text; you could use `innerHTML` instead of course, but that seems like overkill frankly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `innerHTML` of the element and add span tags around the scores to which you apply CSS.

For example:

```
score.innerHTML = `Computer Score: <span style="color:red;">${++computerScore}</span> Your Score: <span style="color:blue;">${playerScore}</span>`
```

You can also use classes:

```
score.innerHTML = `Computer Score: <span class="computer-score">${++computerScore}</span> Your Score: <span class="player-score">${playerScore}</span>`
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a class or using `strong` tag and then styling it in css separately.

Comment: @HaoWu  Hi Hao, can you show me how this can be done? I'm a beginner and have never done it. I can do the styling in CSS, just don't know how I can get the output from javascript.

Comment: My question is: how can I apply things like padding and margin on the score in CSS? The reason I am asking is because as long as I get the output, I can change the color, and do padding and margin in CSS instead of doing it in Javascript.

Comment: @Parham You can use a class instead, e.g. `<span class="yourclass">${computerScore}</span>`. You can style it with CSS like so: `.yourclass{color: red; margin: 5px;}`

Answer (score 1):

First thing's first, you're missing a closing `</div>` tag just before the closing `</main>` tag. In the examples below that error/typo has been fixed.

As you're new to JavaScript – and possibly HTML and CSS – I'll try to work through this relatively slowly and in stages. While you have a 'simple problem' to fix the first thing I'm going to do is tidy up the presentation, and then I'll show you a means by which you can reduce the amount of content you're updating on the page.

The presentation changes I'm going to implement are primarily to reduce scrolling up and down in order more easily visualise what's going on, and changing. To do that we'll be using CSS Grid, with the following CSS:

```
/* We use the universal selector ('*') to select all elements on
   the page, and also we select all of the ::before and ::after
   pseudo-elements; here we reset margin and padding to a known
   default (what the default is doesn't matter, just that you know
   what it is), and set all matching elements to the border-box
   means of box-sizing: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  /* We use CSS grid to layout the contents of the <main> element: */
  display: grid;
  /* We define a two-column layout, using the repeat() function, with
     each column taking one fractional unit of the available space: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  /* We define the width - using the CSS clamp() function as being
     50vw (fifty percent of the width of the viewport, with a
     minimum size of 200px and a maximum size of 600px: */
  width: clamp(200px, 50vw, 600px);
  /* A 1em top and bottom margin, with margin auto for left and right,
     this automatically centers the <main> element within its parent
     container: */
  margin: 1em auto;
  /* defining a gap between the grid-items (the child elements within
     an element set to display: grid); this also applies to elements 
     that are children of 'display: flex' elements: */
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper {
  /* places the element in the first column of the defined grid,
     and extending it to the last column of that defined grid: */
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  /* anticipating at least two other elements to be added to this
     element ('scissors' and 'paper', unless you're playing 'rock,
     paper, scissors, lizard, Spock') so setting up the container
     to accept, and lay out, more elements automatically and
     predictably: */
  display: flex;
  /* allowing the flex-item elements to wrap into a new row (or
     column) if necessary: */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* flex-items will be laid out spaced evenly with space between
     the elements and their parent-element's boundaries: */
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container button {
  /* to show interactivity on hover: */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.results::before {
  /* using CSS generated content to display a header/title/hint
     as to what the element is for: */
  content: "Results: ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```js
function computerPlay() {
  let values = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'],
    valueToUse = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
  return valueToUse;
};

const rock = document.querySelector('#rock');
const paper = document.querySelector('#paper');
const scissors = document.querySelector('#scissors');
let computerSelection = document.querySelector('.computerSelection');
let result = document.querySelector('.result');
let score = document.querySelector('.computerScore', computerScore = 0, 'playerScore', playerScore = 0);


rock.addEventListener('click', pickRock)

function pickRock() {
  let comp = computerPlay() //the variable comp had to be created. Otherwirse, if I use computerPlay() in if statements, sometimes the text content would not appear. See stackoverflow comment.
  if (comp === 'Rock') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Rock";
    result.textContent = "It's a Tie!"
    score.textContent = `Computer Score: ${computerScore +=0} Your Score: ${playerScore +=0}`

  } else if (comp === 'Paper') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Paper";
    result.textContent = "Sorry! Paper beats Rock";
    score.textContent = `Computer Score: ${computerScore +=1} Your Score: ${playerScore +=0}`

  } else if (comp === 'Scissors') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Scissors";
    result.textContent = "Great Job! Rock beats Scissors";
    score.textContent = `Computer Score: ${computerScore +=0} Your Score: ${playerScore +=1}`
  }
};
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: clamp(200px, 50vw, 600px);
  margin: 1em auto;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f903;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.results::before {
  content: "Results: ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h1>
    <h3>Instructions:</h3>
    <p>You will be playing against the computer. There will be a total of 3 rounds. Good luck!</p>
    <h2 id="choose">Choose:</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <button>
      <img id="rock" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/477914-200.png">
    </button>
  </div>
  <!-- The following <div> was changed from div.wrapper to div.results,
       since while it remains a wrapping element, its role is different:
       it exists to present the results or outcome. Name your components
       appropriately and meaningfully, that way maintenance becomes easier
       because you know where to look and what each section is for -->
  <div class="results">
    <p class='computerSelection'></p>
    <p class='result'></p>
    <p class='computerScore'></p>
    <p class='playerScore'></p>
    <p class='finalResult'></p>
  </div>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gh79qxeb/).

Next we'll tidy up the JavaScript and correct something that appears to be an error in your code; first all the variables that won't change will be declared with `const` (you have a peculiar mix of `const` and `let` in your code), we'll fix the bizarre use of `document.querySelector()`:

```
let score = document.querySelector('.computerScore', computerScore = 0, 'playerScore', playerScore = 0);
```

I can intuit your intention, that it should somehow select both the `p.computerScore` and `p.playerScore` elements while initialising the relevant variables; but while the variables are initialised (much against my expectations) `document.querySelector()` will &ndash and *can* – only ever return *one* element-node or `null`. The outcome of that misunderstanding is that you were only ever updating the `p.computerScore` element's text content, rather than using both elements as your HTML suggests you intended.

So, that said: the amended JavaScript:

```
// There was nothing wrong here, except that you initialised
// a variable purely in order to return it in the next line;
// this is a matter of preference and personal taste but I
// removed the variable instantiation and simply returned the
// result directly:
function computerPlay() {
  const values = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
    return values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
}

// You were using document.querySelector() so many times that,
// just to save your fingertips, it was worth defining a
// simple function (using Arrow syntax) to reduce the need to
// repeatedly type a longer method-call; here the function
// dQS() is defined as accepting an 'el' argument and will
// pass that argument to the inner document.querySelector()
// and simply returning the result:
const dQS = (el) => document.querySelector(el),

  // here all the document.querySelector() calls have been
  // changed, and still work perfectly:
  rock = dQS('#rock'),
  paper = dQS('#paper'),
  scissors = dQS('#scissors'),
  computerSelection = dQS('.computerSelection'),
  result = dQS('.result'),
  computerScoreElement = dQS('.computerScore'),
  // you were never getting, and therefore never using, this
  // element in your original code, I assumed - as the paragraph
  // above states - that you meant to, so I changed this around
  // in order that you could:
  playerScoreElement = dQS('.playerScore');

// all preceding variables are constants, but the scores will
// necessarily change therefore we declare with 'let' rather
// than const:
let computerScore = 0,
  playerScore = 0;

rock.addEventListener('click', pickRock)

function pickRock() {
  const comp = computerPlay();

  if (comp === 'Rock') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Rock";
    result.textContent = "It's a Tie!"
    // here the score doesn't change, so there's no need
    // to adjust the score; therefore that's been removed.

  } else if (comp === 'Paper') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Paper";
    result.textContent = "Sorry! Paper beats Rock";

    // here only the computerScore variable changes, so we
    // update only that score; we use the increment operator
    // as a prefix because we want to increment the variable
    // and then return it (computerScore++ would return the
    // variable unchanged, and then increment it):
    ++computerScore;

  } else if (comp === 'Scissors') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Scissors";
    result.textContent = "Great Job! Rock beats Scissors";

    // as above:
    ++playerScore;
  }

  // here we update the scores in the elements:
  computerScoreElement.textContent = `Computer: ${computerScore}`;
  playerScoreElement.textContent = `Player: ${playerScore}`;
}
```

```js
function computerPlay() {
  const values = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
  return values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
}

const dQS = (el) => document.querySelector(el),
  rock = dQS('#rock'),
  paper = dQS('#paper'),
  scissors = dQS('#scissors'),
  computerSelection = dQS('.computerSelection'),
  result = dQS('.result'),
  computerScoreElement = dQS('.computerScore'),
  playerScoreElement = dQS('.playerScore');
let computerScore = 0,
  playerScore = 0;

rock.addEventListener('click', pickRock)

function pickRock() {
  const comp = computerPlay();

  if (comp === 'Rock') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Rock";
    result.textContent = "It's a Tie!"

  } else if (comp === 'Paper') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Paper";
    result.textContent = "Sorry! Paper beats Rock";
    ++computerScore;

  } else if (comp === 'Scissors') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Scissors";
    result.textContent = "Great Job! Rock beats Scissors";
    ++playerScore;
  }

  computerScoreElement.textContent = `Computer: ${computerScore}`;
  playerScoreElement.textContent = `Player: ${playerScore}`;
}
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: clamp(200px, 50vw, 600px);
  margin: 1em auto;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f903;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.results::before {
  content: "Results: ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h1>
    <h3>Instructions:</h3>
    <p>You will be playing against the computer. There will be a total of 3 rounds. Good luck!</p>
    <h2 id="choose">Choose:</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <button>
      <img id="rock" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/477914-200.png">
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
    <p class='computerSelection'></p>
    <p class='result'></p>
    <p class='computerScore'></p>
    <p class='playerScore'></p>
    <p class='finalResult'></p>
  </div>
</main>
```

So now, while we've slightly improved your JavaScript, we're still left with the question you asked: how can we easily color the scores without changing the color of all the text?

There are two obvious – sensible – approaches (and the use of `innerHTML` isn't really sensible since you're destroying and recreating parts of the DOM on each call to the `pickRock()` function.

The first option is to use a nested element in the HTML, such as a `<span>`, and the second is to use CSS generated content (in either of two different ways).

So, with a nested `<span>` (other elements are available), only there are three changes required:

- Adjust the selectors in the JavaScript,
- Update the CSS to style the `<span>` elements, and
- Insert the relevant HTML.

```js
function computerPlay() {
  const values = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
  return values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
}

const dQS = (el) => document.querySelector(el),
  rock = dQS('#rock'),
  paper = dQS('#paper'),
  scissors = dQS('#scissors'),
  computerSelection = dQS('.computerSelection'),
  result = dQS('.result'),
  // note the adjusted selectors below, selecting a
  // <span> which is the direct child of the '.computerScore'
  // element, and likewise with the '.playerScore':
  computerScoreElement = dQS('.computerScore > span'),
  playerScoreElement = dQS('.playerScore > span');
let computerScore = 0,
  playerScore = 0;

rock.addEventListener('click', pickRock)

function pickRock() {
  const comp = computerPlay();

  if (comp === 'Rock') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Rock";
    result.textContent = "It's a Tie!"

  } else if (comp === 'Paper') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Paper";
    result.textContent = "Sorry! Paper beats Rock";
    ++computerScore;

  } else if (comp === 'Scissors') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Scissors";
    result.textContent = "Great Job! Rock beats Scissors";
    ++playerScore;
  }

  computerScoreElement.textContent = computerScore;
  playerScoreElement.textContent = playerScore;
}
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: clamp(200px, 50vw, 600px);
  margin: 1em auto;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f903;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.results::before {
  content: "Results: ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

/* The CSS to style the relevant <span> elements, obviously
   they're both the same here but equally obviously they
   can be adjusted individually to your preference: */
.computerScore > span,
.playerScore > span {
  color: darkblue;
  font-weight: 900;
}
/* Here we use generated content to insert a starting value of
   zero if - and only if - there is no content at all in the
   relevant element; no white-space, no descendants, no text;
   so as soon as there is any textContent inserted into the span
   it ceases to match the :empty selector and therefore the
   ::before element no longer shows: */
.computerScore > span:empty::before,
.playerScore > span:empty::before {
  content: '0';
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h1>
    <h3>Instructions:</h3>
    <p>You will be playing against the computer. There will be a total of 3 rounds. Good luck!</p>
    <h2 id="choose">Choose:</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <button>
      <img id="rock" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/477914-200.png">
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
    <p class='computerSelection'></p>
    <p class='result'></p>
    <!-- Note the inserted <span> elements below: -->
    <p class='computerScore'>Computer: <span></span></p>
    <p class='playerScore'>Player: <span></span></p>
    <p class='finalResult'></p>
  </div>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gh79qxeb/4/).

One other way is to use only the existing elements and make changes using CSS – and *marginally* reducing the JavaScript – only:

```js
function computerPlay() {
  const values = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
  return values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
}

const dQS = (el) => document.querySelector(el),
  rock = dQS('#rock'),
  paper = dQS('#paper'),
  scissors = dQS('#scissors'),
  computerSelection = dQS('.computerSelection'),
  result = dQS('.result'),
  computerScoreElement = dQS('.computerScore'),
  playerScoreElement = dQS('.playerScore');
let computerScore = 0,
  playerScore = 0;

rock.addEventListener('click', pickRock)

function pickRock() {
  const comp = computerPlay();

  if (comp === 'Rock') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Rock";
    result.textContent = "It's a Tie!"

  } else if (comp === 'Paper') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Paper";
    result.textContent = "Sorry! Paper beats Rock";
    ++computerScore;

  } else if (comp === 'Scissors') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Scissors";
    result.textContent = "Great Job! Rock beats Scissors";
    ++playerScore;
  }
  // here we've reduced the text we're inserting into the document to
  // just the variable:
  computerScoreElement.textContent = computerScore;
  playerScoreElement.textContent = playerScore;
}
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: clamp(200px, 50vw, 600px);
  margin: 1em auto;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f903;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.results::before {
  content: "Results: ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

.computerScore,
.playerScore {
  /* styles the color of all the content, but includes the
     score color: */
  color: #000;
}

.computerScore::before {
  content: 'Computer score: ';
  /* styles the color of the CSS generated content,
     overriding the color defined above: */
  color: orange;
}

.playerScore::before {
  content: 'Player score: ';
  /* styles the color of the CSS generated content,
     overriding the color defined above: */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h1>
    <h3>Instructions:</h3>
    <p>You will be playing against the computer. There will be a total of 3 rounds. Good luck!</p>
    <h2 id="choose">Choose:</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <button>
      <img id="rock" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/477914-200.png">
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
    <p class='computerSelection'></p>
    <p class='result'></p>
    <p class='computerScore'></p>
    <p class='playerScore'></p>
    <p class='finalResult'></p>
  </div>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gh79qxeb/6/).

Further, using yet more CSS generated content – with a sprinkle of CSS custom properties – we can also use the following approach:

```js
function computerPlay() {
  const values = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
  return values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
}

const dQS = (el) => document.querySelector(el),
  rock = dQS('#rock'),
  paper = dQS('#paper'),
  scissors = dQS('#scissors'),
  computerSelection = dQS('.computerSelection'),
  result = dQS('.result'),
  computerScoreElement = dQS('.computerScore'),
  playerScoreElement = dQS('.playerScore');
let computerScore = 0,
  playerScore = 0;

rock.addEventListener('click', pickRock)

function pickRock() {
  const comp = computerPlay();

  if (comp === 'Rock') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Rock";
    result.textContent = "It's a Tie!"

  } else if (comp === 'Paper') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Paper";
    result.textContent = "Sorry! Paper beats Rock";
    ++computerScore;

  } else if (comp === 'Scissors') {
    computerSelection.textContent = "Computer's Selection: Scissors";
    result.textContent = "Great Job! Rock beats Scissors";
    ++playerScore;
  }
  // here we use CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty() to set a custom
  // CSS property and its value; we use a template-literal because
  // the value has to be quoted and a template-literal makes that
  // easier to do (this property will be read from CSS):
  computerScoreElement.style.setProperty('--currentComputerScore', `"${computerScore}"`);
  // here we update the HTMLOrForeignElement.dataset API to set
  // a property on the dataset Object of the element, and set its
  // value equal to the playerScore (this creates a custom data-*
  // attribute on the element, from which CSS can read the value
  // via the attr() function:
  playerScoreElement.dataset.current_player_score = playerScore;
}
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: clamp(200px, 50vw, 600px);
  margin: 1em auto;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f903;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.results::before {
  content: "Results: ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

.computerScore,
.playerScore {
  color: #000;
}

.computerScore::before {
  content: 'Computer score: ';
  color: orange;
}

/* here we use the --currentComputerScore
   custom property - defined in JavaScript -
   as the content for the ::after pseudo-
   element; the '0' following the name of
   the custom property is the fall-back value
   in the event the property doesn't resolve
   to a valid value, it's quoted because it
   needs to be a string rather than a CSS 
   length or number: */
.computerScore::after {
  content: var(--currentComputerScore, '0');
  color: darkblue;
}

.playerScore::before {
  content: 'Player score: ';
  color: red;
}

/* here we use the attr() function to retrieve the
   attribute-value of the 'data-current_player_score'
   defined by the JavaScript, and placed on the
   element; unfortunately while the documentation
   states that a default/fallback value might be
   supplied it's use is not currently usable in
   (my current version of) Chromium or Firefox, so
   I'm unable to verify if it might work: */
.playerScore::after {
  content: attr(data-current_player_score);
  color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h1>
    <h3>Instructions:</h3>
    <p>You will be playing against the computer. There will be a total of 3 rounds. Good luck!</p>
    <h2 id="choose">Choose:</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <button>
      <img id="rock" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/477914-200.png">
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
    <p class='computerSelection'></p>
    <p class='result'></p>
    <p class='computerScore'></p>
    <p class='playerScore'><span></span></p>
    <p class='finalResult'></p>
  </div>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gh79qxeb/7/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after).
  - [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr).
  - [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before).
  - [`clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp).
  - [Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
  - "[Using CSS custom properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)."
  - "[Using CSS generated content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Howto/Generated_content)."
  - [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`HTMLOrForeignElement.dataset` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset).